# Auto Focus to the login page

Tags: jquery

I have a login form with username,password with submit,reset buttons.Whenever i start my application i want the cursor shold be by default point to the username.Can any one tell me how to do this.We are using jquery to do this.I am new to jquery.

```
<div class="form-row">
                <div class="label" style="width: 130px;">Username:</div>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input type='text' name='j_username' id='j_username' autocomplete="off" class="input-field-style"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

this is the code i am using for username.

Answer (score 2):

In a script on the same page:

```
$(function() {
    $('#j_username').focus();
});
```

lg,

flo

Comment: Hi Thanks for giving the reply.Can i place this directly in jsp or js file.

Comment: You can, using a regular `<script>`-Tag anywhere, but I would advise against it, as it is good practice to keep you templates and javascript separated.

Comment: if i use like <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     $('#j_username').focus();
  });
 
 </script> this in my jsp page my fire bug is showing missing } in XML expression this.

Comment: could you try wrapping the script in `<![CDATA[` tags?

Comment: i you still have problems, try putting it in an external script.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input type="text" 'text' name='j_username' id='j_username' autocomplete="off" class="input-field-style" autofocus="autofocus"/>
```

link for help:http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_autofocus.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by a little js

```
<body onload="focus()">
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function focus() {
     document.getElementById("#j_username").focus();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use JS for this. HTML5 elements now has an `autofocus` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="j_username" autofocus="autofocus" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answers received until now an "autofocus" attribute exists and can be use but unfortunately, this isn't working in IE:

```
<input type='text' name='j_username' id='j_username' autofocus autocomplete="off" class="input-field-style"/>
```